# I am trying to set MAX_HEAP memory to an odd number , but the heap is being set to the next even number

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

Why can't I set `MAX_HEAP` to an odd number?

When I try to set `max_heap` memory to an odd number , either in tomcat server.bat or in eclipse configuration file,  the final heap size turns out to be the next even number.

Ex : Setting `-Xmx1727m`  as heap memory sets the memory to `1728MB`

Can anyone help me understand why its not taking odd number?

Comment: This should be asked on https://serverfault.com/ not stackoverflow

Comment: You will get better results if you clearly state your question first.  Also provide examples from the configuration files that you are referring to.

Comment: Another tip, use back-ticks around variable names like `MAX_HEAP` so that it's clear that you're referring to a variable somewhere in code.

Answer (score 0):

Computer system memory is in binary language and all data types memory rages are even. If you provide memory in pow(2,n) that works better than just give some even number.